# Erro ao tentar fazer um "UPDATE" usando TypeORM no Postgre (NestJS) | Empty criteria(s) are not allowed for the update method

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

Estou aprendendo NestJS e comecei com o básico, fazendo uma API de crud básico usando TypeORM e Postgre.

Primeiro criei uma tabela no Postgre chamado "users"

```
create table users(
    id_user SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    fullname_user VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email_user VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    password_user VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    role_user INTEGER NOT NULL,
    firsttime_user boolean NOT NULL,
    isactive_user boolean NOT NULL
)
```

No nest defini minha entity: (user.entity.ts)

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User {
    @PrimaryColumn({ type: 'integer' })
    id_user: number;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 100 })
    fullname_user: string;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 150 })
    email_user: string;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 300 })
    password_user: string;

    @Column({ type: 'integer', default: 0 })
    role_user: number;

    @Column({ type: 'boolean', default: true })
    firsttime_user: boolean;

    @Column({ type: 'boolean', default: false })
    isactive_user: boolean;
}
```

E na minha Controller criei os metodos: (users.controller.ts)

```
import { Body, Controller, Delete, Get, Param, Post, Put } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './shared/user.service';

import { User } from './model/user.entity'

@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(
      private userService: UserService) 
      {}

  @Get()
  async getAll() {
    return await this.userService.getAll();
  }

  @Get(':id')
  async getById(@Param('id')id: number) : Promise<User> {
    return await this.userService.getById(id);
  }

  @Post()
  async create(@Body() user: User) : Promise<User> {
    return await this.userService.create(user);
  }

  @Put(':id')
  async update(@Param(':id')id: number, @Body() user: User){
    return await this.userService.update(id, user);
  }

  @Delete(':id')
  async delete(@Param('id')id: number){
    return await this.userService.delete(id);
  }


}
```

Meu Service onde ocorre o erro: (user.service.ts)

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from '../model/user.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
      @InjectRepository(User) private readonly repo: Repository<User>
      
      ) { }

  public async getAll() {
    return await this.repo.find();
  }

  public async getById(id: number){
      return await this.repo.findOneOrFail(id);
  }

  public async delete(id: number){
    return await this.repo.delete(id);
  }

  public async update(id: number, user: User){
    return await this.repo.update(id, user);
  }

  public async create(user: User){
    return await this.repo.save(user);
  }
}
```

Utilizando o Insomnia consigo Criar, Deletar, Listar Todos e Listar somente um pelo id. Porém quando tento fazer o update tenho o seguinte erro:

```
[Nest] 37868  - 23/09/2021 10:34:01   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Empty criteria(s) are not allowed for the update method.TypeORMError: Empty criteria(s) are not allowed for the update method.
    at new TypeORMError (C:\Users\gabriel\Documents\projects\nest-api\src\error\TypeORMError.ts:7:9)
    at EntityManager.update (C:\Users\gabriel\Documents\projects\nest-api\src\entity-manager\EntityManager.ts:496:35)  
    at Repository.update (C:\Users\gabriel\Documents\projects\nest-api\src\repository\Repository.ts:241:29)
    at UserService.update (C:\Users\gabriel\Documents\projects\nest-api\src\users\shared\user.service.ts:26:28)        
    at UsersController.update (C:\Users\gabriel\Documents\projects\nest-api\src\users\users.controller.ts:29:35)       
    at C:\Users\gabriel\Documents\projects\nest-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:38:29 
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\gabriel\Documents\projects\nest-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28 
    at C:\Users\gabriel\Documents\projects\nest-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```

Imagino que estou usando o metodo de forma errada, porém na documentação está assim. Como fazer esse update de maneira correta?

Answer (score 0):

O erro estava aqui:

```
@Put(':id')
async update(@Param(':id')id: number, @Body() user: User){
    return await this.userService.update(id, user);
}
```

No `@Param` o `id` não tem `:` só no `Decorator` do verbo http.

Conforme o própio TypeORM estava retornando:

> Empty criteria(s) are not allowed for the update method

O meu `criteria` (que era o `id`) estava *undefined* e no método `update()` do TypeORM e este não pode ser vazio.

Answer (score -1):

Eu resolvi isso alterando uma classe de mapeamento.

O Dto de upload tinha id, name, slug, no entanto, o método de upload esperava o id também!

Mas o meu mapper removia essa propriedade

```
  public static toEntity(input: BrandCreateInput): Brand {
    const entity = new Brand()
    entity.name = input.name
    entity.slug = input.slug
    entity.logo = ''
    return entity
  }
```

Portanto, quando esse valor chegava ao meu repository, ele informava o erro:

```
 "message": "Empty criteria(s) are not allowed for the update method.",
```

Resolvi fazendo um mapper para Update e resolveu

```
  public static toUpdateEntity(input: BrandUpdateInput): Brand {
    const entity = new Brand()
    entity.id = input.id
    entity.name = input.name
    entity.slug = input.slug
    return entity
  }
```

Em resumo, o erro ocorre porque você não está enviando uma propriedade necessária em sua classe de repositório.